# Using AWK i need to get output

Tags: awk

file1

```
1
2
3
4
5
a
b
c
```

file2

```
1*a*b*c*d
2*a*d*e*d
3*a*b*y*d
6*a*b*c*d
7*a*b*c*d
8*a*b*c*d
9*a*b*c*d
10*a*b*c*d
```

REQ 1:  print unmatched records ( from file 1)

REQ2:print matched records (data from file 2)

Comment: can you give the expected output

Comment: unmatched=4 5 a b c   matched=1*a*b*c*d 2*a*b*c*d 3*a*b*c*d

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this clarification, as it is easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Matched**

```
$ awk -F\* 'NR==FNR{Arr[$0];next}($1 in Arr)' file1 file2
1*b*c*d
2*a*d*e*d
3*a*b*y*d
```

**unmatched**

```
$ awk -F\* 'NR==FNR{a=substr($0,1,1);Arr[a];next}!($0 in Arr)' file2 file1
4
5
a
b
c
```

if you provide the real and good example data, then it's easy for us to give more realistic solution

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {f2[$1];next} !($0 in f2)' file1 file2
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {f2[$1];next} ($0 in f2)' file2 file1
```